# Choosing MLE(Maximum likelihood estimator) from three different estimators(Uniform distribution)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2....X_{2n}$ be random sample from $U(\theta,\theta+1)$. Consider the following three estimators for $\theta,\theta\in R$

$$T_1=x_{(n)}$$
$$T_2=\dfrac{x_{(1)}+x_{(n)}}{2}$$
$$T_3=\dfrac{x_{(1)}+x_{(n)}}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Then

$(A)$ $T_1$ and $T_3$ are both MLE of $\theta$ while $T_2$ is not

$(B)$ $T_3$ is unique  MLE of $\theta$

$(C)$ $T_3$ is an MLE of $\theta$ while $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not

$(D)$$T_1$ and $T_2$ are both MLE of $\theta$ while $T_3$ is not

**My input:**
Every statistic satisfying following condition are MLE of $\theta $

$ \theta \leq x_{(1)}\leq x_{(2)}....x_{(n)}\leq\theta +1$

$ \theta \leq x_{(1)}\leq x_{(2)}....(x_{(n)}-1)\leq\theta$

That means $x_{(n)}$ can't be MLE of $\theta$ where as $(x_{(n)}-1)$ can.

$T_2 \ \ $and $\ \  T_3$  follow my condition $T_1$ doesn't.(Please correct me if there is something wrong in my input). And any of my option doesn't matches up with my thought process. Did i do something wrong or it's just typo in the options. And what could be an alternative way to think about these types of problems. 
Original image:http://prntscr.com/i8a5py

Comment: As you say, $x_{(n)}-1$ is an MLE.  So too is $x_{(1)}$.  And so too is anything in between.  But you may have the inequalities the wrong way round in your second list:  $x_{(n)}-1 \le \theta \le x_{(1)}$, which is a justification for liking $T_2$ as being unbiased

Comment: @Henry It should be like this right ?$$ \theta-1 \leq x_{(1)}\leq x_{(2)}....(x_{(n)}-1)\leq\theta$$

Comment: No - I do not think that quite works either. in particular  $ x_{(n)}-1 \le x_{(1)}$.  Nor do I see how to fit $x_{(2)}$ and the other intermediate order statistics sensibly into the expression.

Comment: @Henry i was just subtracting 1 from both sides. I ll just stick to this one $x_{(n)}-1 \le \theta \le x_{(1)}$

Comment: @Henry I wish i had any good teacher around me. I am just doing these thing on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to care for the following:
\begin{align}
\theta \leq x_{(1)} \leq ... \leq x_{(n)} \leq \theta +1 
\end{align}
That is exactly what you would obtain if you would look at the Likelihood (that is what you did right?).

So we want that $$\tag{1}\theta\leq x_{(1)} \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \  x_{(n)}\leq \theta+1$$ and that implies the inequalities you had in the middle. The likelihood function is constant (which constant?) and it is nonzero if the inequality in $(1)$ is statisfied. That means that an MLE $T$ satisfies:
\begin{align}
x_{(n)}-1\leq T \leq x_{(1)}
\end{align} 
Now you immediately see that it cannot be unique, so we can forget $(B)$.

Let's look at the estimators you have. First $T_1$ does not satisfy $T_1\leq x_{(1)}$ in general so we drop it. Secondly $T_2$ does not satisfy $T_2\leq x_{(1)}$ either so we throw it away. There is no need to check if $T_3$ is an MLE, there is only one option left, namely $(C)$. I'll advice you to check it yourself that it indeed satisfies $(1)$.

Comment: But $T_2$ is arithmetic mean of all order statistics ,it will lie between $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(2)}$  and as we said any statistic between $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(2)}$ is MLE of $\theta$

Comment: @Damn1o1 why $x_{\color{red}{(2)}}$? And not $x_{(n)}$. We have $$T_2=\frac{x_{(1)}+x_{(n)}}{2}\geq \frac{x_{(1)}+x_{(1)}}{2}=x_{(1)}$$ but we required $T\leq x_{(1)}$ remember?

Comment: Everything got cleared thank you shashi and yes there is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $X_{(n)}-X_{(1)} \le 1$. Second, if $T_i$ is an MLE of $\theta$ then $$X_{(n)}-1 \le T_i \le X_{(1)},$$
as you found.

Amongst the given $T_i$'s, only $T_3$ satisfies the above condition. Therefore, the correct option is (C).

Comment: But $T_2$ is arithmetic mean of all order statistics ,it will lie between $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(2)}$  and as we said any statistic between $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(2)}$ is MLE of $\theta$

Comment: @Damn1o1 Note that $\theta \le X_{(1)}$. Therefore, $T_2$ must be less than or equal to $X_{(1)}$, which is not the case.

Comment: So this statement is wrong isnt it ? "Every statistic satisfying following condition are MLE of θ $ \theta \leq x_{(1)}\leq x_{(2)}....x_{(n)}\leq\theta +1$" 
Condition should be this $X_{(n)}-1 \le T_i \le X_{(1)}$

Comment: In my mind i have this intuition that all the order statistics statistics are MLE.

Comment: Replace $\theta$ with $T_i$, you will get $X_{(n)}-1 \le T_i \le X_{(1)}$.

Comment: Both are same thing yes i know but in my mind i was thinking different anyways i am just having dumb thoughts. Thank you.